# Map is not rendering ReactJs PROPS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

map is not rendering, I created an array in a component and used props to access, but it's not rendering, someone could help me?

```
import React from "react";
import poke from '../../assets/poke.png';
import { CardProjetos } from './PortfolioStyled';

    const Portfolio = () => {
      const projects = [
        {
            id: 1,
            image: poke,
            title: 'Pokedex',
            description: ' React com axios para requisição de API do pokemon para listar os pokemons e mostrar tela com detalhes pelo ID',

        }, 
        {
          id: 2,
          image: poke,
          title: 'Test',
          description: 'test is not rendering',

      }
    ]
    return (
          <div>
            <CardProjetos itens={projects} />
          </div>

    )
    }

  export default Portfolio;






const Projetos = ({itens}) => {

  return ( 
    <>
    {itens.map((item) => (
    <div>
          <h1>{item.title}</h1>
          <h1>{item.description}</h1>
    </div>
))}
    </>
   )
}



export default Projetos;
```

I tried a lot of things, but it simply doesnt render. The page is blank.
I put two codes, the first one I created an array
The second is to use this value.
I think it's something simple, but I'm not seeing it.
Could some one help me?

Comment: do you have any error or warning in console?

Comment: no, it's not showing any error in console :(

Comment: Have you checked to see if `itens` is an empty array?

Comment: what is CardProjetos, I only see code of Projetos. Are they same?

Comment: I just checked and the itens props is empty, but I don't know why it's happening .The CarProjetos it's just a styled-components to stylize the cards

Comment: check my answer below. I think the problem was that you didn't include the return inside the map func

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The components you are passing the `itens` prop to is called `CardProjectos` which you are importing on line 3. `Projectos` as far as I can see is declared but never called within the same file.

You can check this sandbox if it helps: https://codesandbox.io/s/headless-surf-57se9s?file=/src/Portofolio.js

Comment: The CarProjetos it's just a styled-components to stylize the cards :(. but the itens prop is passing empty, I don't know why

Comment: There is probably a silly mistake somewhere like misspelling of a prop or something. Also the code is hard to read because of different spacing on some lines and this will make debugging harder for you.

Comment: Thank you!! I'll make the adjustments

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from "react";
import poke from '../../assets/poke.png';
import { CardProjetos } from './PortfolioStyled';

const Portfolio = () => {
    const projects = [
        {
            id: 1,
            image: poke,
            title: 'Pokedex',
            description: ' React com axios para requisição de API do pokemon para listar os pokemons e mostrar tela com detalhes pelo ID',

        }, 
        {
          id: 2,
          image: poke,
          title: 'Test',
          description: 'test is not rendering',

      }
    ]
    return ( <CardProjetos items={projects} /> )
}

export default Portfolio;


const Projetos = ({items}) => {

  return (
      {
          items.map((item, index)=>{
              return (
              <div key={index} >
                <h1>{item.title}</h1>
                <h1>{item.description}</h1>
              </div>
              )
          })
      }
   )
}



export default Projetos;
```